# Different methods to display NSarray

Tags: iphone

I have an array which store highscore records, besides using tableview, is there another way i can display my array.

Comment: You aren't asking the right question- it depends on how you want to display the data. Whether it's stored in an array, a dictionary, XML, or anything else is irrelevant.

Comment: the data is store in NSUserDefaults. I need to display it

Comment: Ok, but how do you want it to look?

Answer (score 0):

That's the best way, if you're using an `NSArray` as a datasource; if you don't need the users to interact with the data, you could use a `UIScrollView`, maybe, by adding a `UILabel` for every data row, though this seems clunky.

Your other option, and probably the best option, is to customize the look of the tableview, as shown [in this tutorial.](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)

Comment: You could loop through your array and add UILabels to the scrollview, and set its width to accomodate all pages.

Comment: does this answer your question?

Comment: can you provide me some example.sorry. i am new to the coding

Comment: If you're new, then you definitely want to go with UITableView. It was designed to show data from arrays, and nothing does it better. Try this tutorial to get started: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/introduction-to-table-view/

Comment: o. But i having a view controller and from there i want to display the table and it is giving me alot of problem.

Comment: Try using a nib file to lay out your data, and make an outlet to that. It really is the best way -- just google the errors you're getting, and success will come. Soon, you'll wonder why you had any trouble at all!